# R collapse rows by group with non-missing values when values are character

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to collapse/aggregate/summarise rows by group keeping only non-missing values, where values are characters. Here's a reproducible example.

```
df = data.frame(store = c("A","A", "B","B"),
                item1=c("apple","","milk",""),
                item2=c("","pear","","bread"))

df
  store item1 item2
1     A apple      
2     A        pear
3     B  milk      
4     B       bread
```

I hope to change df as the following

```
df2
  store item1 item2
1     A apple  pear
2     B  milk bread
```

I've tried using `summarise_all` with `nchar(.) > 0`as the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
df %>%
  group_by(store) %>%
  summarise_all( ~ + any(nchar(.) > 0))
```

Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(store) %>%
 summarise_all(~ .[nchar(.) > 1])

  store item1 item2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     apple pear 
2 B     milk  bread
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) pivot** Reshape to long form, remove the `""` elements and reshape back.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  filter(value != "") %>%
  pivot_wider
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  store item1 item2
  <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 A     apple pear 
2 B     milk  bread
```

**2) max**  Another approach is to take the maximum value within group excluding NA's.  This converts the item columns to character whereas the output of (1) is factor columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(store) %>%
  summarize_all(~ max(as.character(.), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  store item1 item2
  <fct> <chr> <chr>
1 A     apple pear 
2 B     milk  bread
```

Comment: Didn't know that max function works for characters as well. Thank you!

Comment: note that you need to be careful with your `group_by()` for the `max()` solution to work.  When grouping by multiple columns, this may not have the desired result